# Testing file write failure with iostate flags

Tags: c++

I have a case where my program writes to disk, and the log files may be deleted by someone, so next time the write would fail. Can we repeat the write operation after opening the file again by checking stream flags instead of checking if the file is open for every write ?

Also how would the performance be comparing (1) Stat to check file exists before writing (2) using stream flags to verify if file exists and rewriting in case of failure.

Can someone provide an example of using stream flags to detect if write to file did not succeed. I try to create filestream and sleep for 5 seconds and delete the file from shell before program resumes. The file stream error bits are not set. Why?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

      ofstream file_stream;

      file_stream.open("something");
      system("sleep 5");
      for(int i = 0 ; i < 2000 ; i++) {
              file_stream << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!

              if(file_stream.fail()) {
                      cout << "file is gone ?";

              }   
      }   
      file_stream.close();
      return 0;
}
```

Over here when i execute the program and delete the something file from another terminal, I never get the file is gone. Neither is something created again.

Comment: You're saying you want to check the stream state after each write instead of doing `if (myfile.is_open())` before every write?

Comment: yes, although myfile.is_open is not an accurate reflection, if the file gets deleted , the stream is still open and it will try to write

Comment: What OS is this? On most *nix OSes, someone removing a file that you have open will not cause write failures (in fact, you generally won't even be able to tell that the file has been deleted, unless you specifically test for it). If you want to recreate the file as quickly as possible after deletion and make sure stuff after that gets stored, then you'll have to open/write/close each time, but that's going to hurt performance...

Comment: twalberg can you point to some resouces which describe what you said about *nix not being able to tell file does not exist to the stream

Comment: @RaviNankani I don't know of any specific explicit documentation to that effect, but on most file systems, an open file handle referencing a specific file will prevent that file from being completely deleted - the name may be removed from the directory, preventing new processes from accessing the file, but the data blocks and other metadata generally won't be freed up until the last open file descriptor referencing that file is closed. As a result, further writes to the file (and reads) will continue to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. The stream state `ios_base::failbit` or `ios_base::badbit` is set if a write operation fails in some way.

Comment: can you tell me why bad does not return true, even if i delete the file after it has been opened and before i write to it?

Comment: Only `failbit` is set if the file failed to open. But if your file is an output file the file will automatically be created for you.

Comment: can you have a look at my sample now

Comment: @RaviNankani Oops. I see what you're saying now. I will have to look into this... :)